# NDK_TOOLCHAIN is defined to the unsupported value

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-ndk, toolchain

I'm woking on running an irrlicht android sample project in android emulator using android-ndk, When I have tried building that sample , the following error occurred:

```
/Android/android-ndk-r9/ndk-build V=1 NDK_TOOLCHAIN=arm-2010q1 

/Android/android-ndk-r9/build/core/init.mk:555: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

Android NDK: NDK_TOOLCHAIN is defined to the unsupported value arm-2010q1  

Android NDK: Please use one of the following values: arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.2 arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.3 mipsel-linux-android-4.6 mipsel-linux-android-4.8 mipsel-linux-android-clang3.2 mipsel-linux-android-clang3.3 x86-4.6 x86-4.8 x86-clang3.2 x86-clang3.3
```

Then in config.mk file, I have changed:

```
TOOLCHAIN_ABIS := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

to:

```
TOOLCHAIN_ABIS := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
```

and to:

```
TOOLCHAIN_ABIS := armeabi armeabi-v7a 4.6
```

In Application.mk file, Changed:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

to:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

and then to:

```
 APP_ABI := arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
```

Nothing changed. I dint got anything more than this, when I googled it. Does anyone know the solution to this issue. Where can I find `arm-2010q1` and how to change it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you looking for `arm-2010q1`? It's 2013 on my calendar! No need to specify `NDK_TOOLCHAIN` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @Alex Cohn  Smart, I'm trying to learn. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

NDK_TOOLCHAIN=arm-2010q1 is passed directly to your ndk-build command, you only need to avoid setting it if you don't have this toolchain and keep the default one.

If you aren't calling the ndk-build script by yourself but from eclipse, you can go into your project properties and revert the C/C++ build settings:

[image: C/C++ build project properties]

Comment: Yup ,I've fixed that by changing `Build` and `clean` fields in `C/C++ Build -> Behaviour`. Thank you anyway.